# put config in secure place, can not link the files

Tags: php, html, ajax

Am trying to use a config file for a database and rating script but the problem is the config file is in this directory :

```
       website.com/include/config.php  aka websitename/include/config.php
```

The rating script needs the config and is accessed like this:
           include_once("config.php");

I want the config to be in:
      "/files/website/"
A directory level up from the website root folder.

I have been trying with:
         "../files/website/" and other variations but can not figure out how to link them.

I have managed to put one config file and access it, but with this ajax rating script the only way for it to work is to have the config in the /include/ folder next to:
    rating_process.php           - has this link : include("inc/config.php");

```
     rating_functions.php         - has this link : include_once("config.php");

     rating_total_functions.php   - has this link : include("inc/config.php");
```

Hope i've explained myself here

Right, looking at my hosting now:
          $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; outputs this:  /foldy/homepages/11/username/htdocs/webbysite

My index file is located at: /foldy/homepages/11/username/htdocs/webbysite/index.php
The included rating script is located in: /foldy/homepages/11/username/htdocs/webbysite/include/

I want the config to be in /foldy/homepages/11/username/htdocs/secretfiles/config.php

Am trying to some how go out of: webbysite folder and then into secretfiles (sibling folders)

I have tried adding ../ and so on, but am missing something obviously :(

Comment: are you concerned about security?  having the settings for your db in a directory that a user could access via the web?

Comment: yeah security is some what of an issue, not major but to some level.

Comment: if you have tried ../../secretfiles/config.php and still no luck then i am guessing you will need to change permissions on the file that your ajax is calling, the ../../secretfiles/config.php script, and maybe even the directories that contain these files

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$configLocation = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../files/website/config.php';
include_once($configLocation)
```

Comment: thanks, tried but, would just add the string to the document root, didn't actually go back up a level

Comment: ".." signifies the parent directory, if you put that in the include string it will move up one directory. ".." is a part of the Unix/Linux operating system and is always available. The code I posted looks for the "files" directory one level above the current document root.

Answer (score 0):

> but the problem is the config file is in this directory

it is not a problem at all.
just keep it as is.

Concerning your particular problem, your problem is that you don't know where you want to put your file. `/files/website/` is not likely a right path and it is apparently not one level high from webroot.

So, first of all make your mind about the right path to the directory and it's relative position to the web root

Answer (score 0):

if you are concerned about security ( because your config file contains the db details ) i would place the db config file outside the site root folder and then `require_once('../../dbConfig.php')` from the script that's creating xml or json for your ajax

more exactly ...
  your site folder might be here: `/var/www/html`

set a virtual host (done differently on Linux and Windows) and point your domain to a sub folder inside `/html` so that the new path to the site root is `/var/www/html/site`.

then place your config file in `/var/www/html` and call it from your scripts inside your `/site` folder using `require_once('../dbConfig.php`)`.

your db details are outside the site folder

Comment: The first part is what I need.

To connect and show my information am using:               require_once("../configfiles/config.php");

THat loads ok, but the ajax rating script also tries to connect to the a config to connect to the db to insert votes which is inside: /website/include/

This is the part that breaks. Not sure where to start now, there are  3 php files for the script and a js files.  confused as shit now

Comment: `../../secretfiles/config.php` should get you there.  if you still have trouble i'm guessing it's a permissions issue and you'll need to chmod the script that your ajax is calling